# How to force SO to accept a bad title?

Tags: discussion, edits, title, quality-filter

This question:  [RTools not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54065092/2554330)  was migrated from https://stats.stackexchange.com, which seems like a reasonable decision.  However, it has a subject line which would not be acceptable, as well as serious formatting problems.

When I tried to fix the formatting, my edit was not accepted because the title was not acceptable.

1. Can I force it to accept my partial edit?  I don't want to edit the title.
2. How can it be acceptable to migrate a bad title to Stack Overflow, but not to edit a post afterwards?

Comment: Just remove the question mark.

Comment: What's the problem with changing the title to an acceptable one?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev:  The question is unreadable as it is.  I don't know what would be an appropriate title.

Comment: In this case, I think the question is best closed as unclear. If you make the question readable and still don't know what it's about, then there wasn't much point in making it readable.

Comment: "What's the problem with changing the title to an acceptable one?" - what if just do not have time or experience to add a better title?

Comment: "In this case, I think the question is best closed as unclear." - unreadable is not the same as unclear.

Answer (score 16):

As has already been mentioned in the comments, change the title to be an acceptable one.

If you want to edit a post, you must look at the entirety of the post not just the body. That includes the title and the tags. If they need improving, then improve them - especially when the system prompts you do so.

Therefore to answer your points:

1. If you don't want to edit the title then don't edit the post at all.
2. While there are checks made on migration (at least one of the posts tags must exist on the target site, the user isn't suspended or question blocked on the target site, etc.) a check on the title isn't included. If you think it should be then raise a feature request.

Comment: "If you want to edit a post, you must look at the entirety of the post not just the body" - this does not make sense. What is wrong with a partial edit (e.g. removal of typo)?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald The point was that *system* was rejecting the "removal of typo" because the title wasn't acceptable. If the title required edits but was OK as far as the system was concerned then it would have allowed the edits. The OP was asking how to get round system imposed restrictions.