# I cannot edit a question because of a title I didn't change?

Tags: support, bug, edits, error-message

Ok, ok, ok! Hold on; don't get the duplicate hammer out just yet! I know that we have this question here: [Can't edit question - title already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288001/6707985)

I read it. It is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)! This is probably a duplicate but the issue is slightly different *and* considering that the OP is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I thought I would create this post.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31686504/6707985) which is fairly old has some indentation errors I caught and I wanted to clean up. When saving however I got the message:

> "Title cannot contain "Symfony choice type array error".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?"

While not the same "error" message, it appears to be a similar problem.

Is the reason that the question is old and the check was added later?
I only edited the body, why am I blamed for the title? Was there some other automated editing that bypassed restrictions?

---

As there were two duplicate mentions now: I do **NOT** ask what I can do about the error. I am asking for the **reason** I get it.

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as [this answer to the duplicate you mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288018/215552) -- that is, edit the title too.

Comment: I would disagree. I was asking for the reasoning behind the message; not how to resolve it.

Comment: Same comment as towards Heretic Monkey @gnat: I do not want to know what I can do against the error. I am asking for the **reason** it's happening.

Comment: the reason is provided right there, in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378634/839601): "If you want to edit a post, you must look at the entirety of the post not just the body. That includes the title and the tags..." - this is what is expected of editors and this is why system blocks edits that keep inappropriate titles

Comment: I did understand the error message. I understand that the title is of bad quality. The title still has been there before. I am asking for the reason why I as editor face a problem with the post while the OP did not. I even added assumptions on why that might be as clarification of the direction I am going. None of those are similar to what the duplicate answer addresses aside the mention that title checks are not done on migration which does not apply here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Regular Expression that Shog9 posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373958/3270037):

```
^(?=.{0,40}$)(?=.*\b(question(?!\s+mark)|doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|(?<!(visual studio|vs|exit)\s+)code|my)\b).+
```

The title of a question cannot contain "error" if it is less than 41 characters in length.

The title:

> Symfony choice type array error: Unable to transform value for property path "...": Expected an array.

would've been fine.

---

As you guessed this check was added after the question was asked and hence was a valid title when posted, however now if you want to edit the question (even just the body of the post) you must also edit the title to meet the new title requirements (as Heretic Monkey [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379002/i-cannot-edit-a-question-because-of-a-title-i-didnt-change/379003?noredirect=1#comment662924_379002))

Comment: Or... a better suggestion is to add the error message to the title for clarity. The original title is really unclear and too general.

Comment: @AndrewT. Of course, I was clarifying the source of the error rather than suggesting a valid improvement to the title, perhaps *"Symfony choice type array error: Unable to transform value for property path "...": Expected an array."* (I'm not good at question titles :) )

Comment: one would assume adding eligible characters