# Better error messaging when rejecting unedited titles

Tags: feature-request, edits, title

- This is not a duplicate of [Can't edit question - title already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists) because that is not the error I am getting, nor is that the issue.
- This is not a duplicate of [How to force SO to accept a bad title?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378632/how-to-force-so-to-accept-a-bad-title) because I am not trying to do that.
- This is not a duplicate of [I cannot edit a question because of a title I didn't change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379002/i-cannot-edit-a-question-because-of-a-title-i-didnt-change) because that was asking for the policy and posted as a bug report.

This is a simple feature request for better error messaging and tools for the apparently not infrequent case where an editor makes changes to the body of a question and has the edit rejected because the question title, **which the editor did not change**, no longer meets the site's standards.

What happened to me, as happened to the authors of the other mentioned questions, is that I went to edit a question, simply to fix a broken link. The question was titled "[How can I list the taints on my nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43379415/1)", and after fixing the broken link and trying to save my edit, I got the error message:

> Title cannot contain "How can I list the taints on my nodes?".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

In this situation, this error message made me think this was a bug, and I spent 20 minutes on a bug report before I found that this *behavior* is intended, even if this error message is bad. It apparently has led others to the same time-wasting conclusion.

#### Request 1: Different error message for editors

When editing a question, if the system rejects the title but the title has not been changed, please be specific about this in the error message. I suggest a message like this:

> Note to Editor: The original title of this question, "How can I list the taints on my nodes?", no longer meets the site's standards.
>
> Please edit the title to better summarize the question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

#### Request 2: Better guidance about what is wrong with the title

If you ask me, "How can I list the taints on my nodes?" is an excellent summary of the question. I was at a loss to see what was wrong with it, and I am not a noob.

I would therefore like a tool or better explanation of what is wrong with the title or how to fix it. After some more digging, I eventually found [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373958/712765) which pointed me to the problem: the title contains the word "my" and is fewer than 40 characters long.

After figuring that out, I do not object to the restriction, as the title would surely be improved by replacing "my" with "Kubernetes". I'm just upset that I went to make a 2 minute fix to a broken link and it turned into half an hour of digging to understand why I also had to change the title and what to change it to.

#### Request 3: Better error message in general

The message

> Title cannot contain "How can I list the taints on my nodes?".

is not helpful, and also wrong. It is wrong in that the title "kubctl: How can I list the taints on my nodes?" would be acceptable, even though it contains the supposedly forbidden text. Which is also why it is not helpful: it gives no actual guidance as to what the problem is.

At the very least, if the error message were:

> We think you can come up with a better title than "How can I list the taints on my nodes?". Something more descriptive or more specific, perhaps?

then it would not be flat out wrong.